# Hibernate- Fields Lazy Fetching

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, hibernate-mapping

How to add restriction to load only desired fields from entity?
My User table having CustomerUser OneToOne mapping and Transaction table having User as OneToOne maping
So when i load transaction it load user and respective customer, but i dont want to load password and some other fileds from customeruser table.
(Hibernate version 4.2.6)

Comment: Are you loading the transaction in json?

Comment: yes, im fetching json data

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

But for that to work on your fields you have to enable Hibernates Bytecode Enhancer ([some back story](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7573))

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                        <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Another way is to have two entities mapped to the same table. Like CustomerUser could have mapped all the fields that are always loaded, but the CustomerPassword would have only the id and the password itself. Then you would only load the passwords entity when you need it from your service/repository.

This was a common workaround before they fixed the lazy properties ticket. Took like 3 years :P.

Comment: But now my project becomes so vast that, i cant even touch my pojo design. CustomerUser is been used in so many functionalities..

Comment: As far I know there is no other way with Hibernate than those two.

Comment: You probably are going to find soon about EntityGraph and NamedEntityGraph javax.persistence annotations but those are not for fields/properties in Hibernate but for joined entities.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to write Json annotation and fetch type.
e.g:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JsonIgnore
private CustomerUser customerUser;
```

`FetchType.LAZY`does not load the class automatically. `@JsonIgnore` blocks the class to be in the json.

Or,

Lets say you want to load CustomerUser with all its variables except password. What you need to do is to add `@JsonIgnore` to password variable .

```
public class User {
       ....
      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
      @JsonManagedReference
      private CustomerUser customerUser;
      ....
}

public class CustomerUser {

       @Column(name = "username")
       private String username;

       @Column(name = "password")
       @JsonIgnore
       private String password;
       ......
       ...getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so you turned the tables to answer a serialization question instead of mapping question.

Comment: He wants to use Lazy load and loads the transaction in json format. I both explained mapping and serializing

Comment: Of course you are right, and yes this will be appropriate approach if you ignore the lazy fields part of the question and assume that just excluding it in serialization is enough. Yet the question is how not to load it, not how not to serialize it.